# Angular momentum ladder operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, representation-theory

The eigenvalue of the operator $J^2$ is $j(j+1)$. Why does that mean there's only one eigenvalue of $J^2$? As in there's only one value of $j(j+1)$ that's possible? The eigenvalues can only be real, but that doesn't really limit the value of $j(j+1)$ to a single value.

I'm assuming it must be obvious because it isn't explained in my lecture notes. I can't see why though, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: j can be any number $j\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,\cdots\}$ so there are infinitely many eigenvalues.

Comment: Besides the non-negative integers, $j$ can also be a non-negative half-integer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have three self-adjoint operators $J_1, J_2, J_3$ on some Hilbert space, that obey the commutation relations (ignoring comments about the domain of definition)
$$[J_i, J_j]=\sum_{k} i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk}J_k.$$
(This basically means that you have a representation of the angular momentum algebra.)

Suppose further that you have some Hamiltonian operator $H$, which commutes with the angular momentum operators. Then $H$ also commutes with $\vec{J}^2:=J_1^2+J_2^2+J_3^2$ and also $J_i$ commutes with $J^2$. Because the operators commute with $H$, we can pick one of the $J_i$ operators arbitrarily and try to find an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space made of simultaneous eigenvectors of the operators $H$, $J_3$ (corresponding to angular Momentum in the z-direction) and $J^2$.

Using just the above general and abstract setting one may determine that the possible eigenvalues for $J^2$ must be expressible as $\hbar^2 j(j+1)$ for non-negative half integers $j$, that is $j\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0$. This operator is called a "Casimir operator" in that it labels the irreducible representation one is considering (if one is considering one such). I want to stress that the above claims that these are the only POSSIBLE eigenvalues for operators satisfying above commutation relations. It doesn't mean that all of these eigenvalues must always occur depending on what the Hilbert space and the $J_i$ actually are.

Hence it is impossible to tell which of the above possible eigenvalues of $J^2$ actually occur just from the commutation relations alone! Let's look at a few common concrete realizations of this: If you have the angular momentum operators on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$, the possible values for $j$ are actually $\mathbb{N}_0$. The basis of the Hilbert space of simultaneous eigenvectors of $H, L_3, J^2$ is then made of vectors $\psi_{njm}$ labeled by $j$ designating the eigenvalue of $J^2$, $m$ designating the eigenvalue $\hbar m$ of $J_3$ and $n$ somehow designating the eigenvalue of $H$. The angular momentum operators are usually written as $L_i$ rather than $J_i$. The possible values of $m$ for given $j$ in this case are $m\in\{-j,-j+1,\dots,j-1, j\}$.

On the other hand one can consider the representation of "Spin j" where the Hilbert space is $\mathbb{C}^{2j+1}$ and the $J_i$ are given by certain quadratic matrices. The most used one is spin $\frac{1}{2}$ where the $J_i=\frac{\hbar}{2}\sigma_i$ with the Pauli matrices $\sigma_i$. Here the only possible number of $j$ is given by "the $j$ of the representation" which means that in fact the matrices satisfy $J_1^2+J_2^2+J_3^2=\hbar^2j(j+1)\text{I}$ with the identity matrix $\text{I}$.

Hence for your question to be concrete (asking for what values of $j$ actually occur) you must specify what the operators $J_i$ actually are (that is specify what exact representation of the algebra $\text{su}(2)$ you're using.)